# Enable migration visual studio 2012

Tags: c#

Code entered

```
======================================
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext

Problem
=======================================
Enable-Migrations : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
'ContextTypeName'.
At line:1 char:19
+ Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enable-Migrations], Parameter 
   BindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Enable-Migrations
```

Can someone tell me what's the reason for this problem?

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-new-field-to-the-movie-model-and-table) when the problem occurred

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Default project is set correctly. Then enter the command "Enable-Migrations" without any parameters. This will enable Code First Migrations for your default project.  From  http://forums.asp.net/t/1855667.aspx/1?Mvc+4+Enable+Migrations+Problem

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, the problem is because you defined the `MovieDbContext` within the *Movie.cs* class. Create another class under Models folder and copy the code for the `DBContext` over as so:

```
using MvcMovie.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then ran

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext
```

That should fix it.